# transferring data between ViewController without Segues - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a sign up viewController(VC).  Once the user submits his registration details, my remote server responds with a 'registration_success'.  Upon receiving this message, I am able to present a new VC that requests that the user check their email to verify their email address.  I am able to present the new view controller but failing to transfer the user's email address to the new VC.  My code is below:

```
     guard
          let registeredEmail = myArray["email"] as? String else{
          print("cannot find email address")
          return
          }

          let verifyEmailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "emailConfirmVC") as! VerifyEmailViewController
          print("registeredEmail: \(registeredEmail)")
          verifyEmailVC.emailToVerify.text! = registeredEmail
          self.present(verifyEmailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

class VerifyEmailViewController:

```
    class VerifyEmailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var emailToVerify: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

console:

```
 jsonObject: {
email = "tran123@gmail.com";
firstname = Wang;
lastname = tran;
message = "registration_success";
status = 200;
userId = 53;
}
message: registration_success
registeredEmail: tran123@gmail.com
```

I am getting the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

in line: `verifyEmailVC.emailToVerify.text! = registeredEmail`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Don't try to directly set the outlets of another VC.  Instead, set properties in the destination VC and then set the outlets in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: could you put that in code for me. not really sure i understand

Comment: @HarshalValanda - those answer do not apply. As mentioned in the title. I am not using Segues.

Comment: @johnDoe there is all kind of data passing method check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label in the VerifyViewController is nil and you are trying to set value to that lable. Try passing string to your controller like this

```
let verifyEmailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "emailConfirmVC") as! VerifyEmailViewController
print("registeredEmail: \(registeredEmail)")
verifyEmailVC.email = registeredEmail
self.present(verifyEmailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


class VerifyEmailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var emailToVerify: UILabel!
var email: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    emailToVerify.text = email
}
```

Comment: It's `emailToVerify.text = email` still an optional value

Comment: emailToVerify is a UILabel and it has a property 'text' which is optional.  If you pass nil it will not crash but label text will not show on the screen

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code with few correction try below code

```
let verifyEmailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "emailConfirmVC") as! VerifyEmailViewController
      print("registeredEmail: \(registeredEmail)")
      verifyEmailVC.emailToVerifyStr = registeredEmail
      self.present(verifyEmailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In **VerifyEmailViewController**

```
    class VerifyEmailViewController: UIViewController {

    var emailToVerifyStr = ""
    @IBOutlet var emailToVerify: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool){
       super.viewWillAppear(true)
       self.emailToVerify.text = emailToVerifyStr
    }
  }
```

Hope that will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having JSON object used by your high level objects like ViewController is not something I would recommend.

You should consider having a "*Store*" object which receives the JSON, create a **User object**.

Then, you can create your one `init` function to **pass your User object** directly.

Like this :

```
- (instancetype)initWithUser(User *)user {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   self = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"emailConfirmVC"];

   if(self) {
      //default initialization
   }

   return  self;
 }
```